# Is SpelExpression in spring-el thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

```
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("myParam.getValue()");
```

Is the `Expression` class thread safe? I would like to store it in global cache, like `ConcurrentHashMap` to avoid compilation with every access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `Expression` is an interface, not a class. But, yes, if your `parser` is a standard `SpelExpressionParser`, the resulting `SpelExpression` implementation is thread-safe. In general, evaluation contexts are too, as long as you don't mutate them (e.g. changing variables, functions) while being used.